# How do I retrieve multiple vpc endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

ERROR: no matching VPC Endpoint found
(error referring to data code block)

I am trying to retrieve multiple endpoints from data "aws_vpc_endpoint" resource. I created locals to retrieve service name for multiple endpoints that share the first few characters. Afterwards, the endpoints have unique characters to identify them individually.

I am wanting the data resource to loop through the data and retrieve each endpoint that shares those few characters. Then grab each endpoint id for "aws_route". FYI: The endpoints are being created from resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall" The main thing to look at in this code snippet is locals, data, and  the last line for resource "aws_route" How can I express in locals that the service_name does not end there and the rest of the string is unique to the endpoint without hard coding each service_name?

```hcl
locals {
  endpoints = {
    service_name = "com.amazonaws.vpce.us-east-1.vpce-svc-"
  }
}

data "aws_vpc_endpoint" "firewall-endpoints" {
  for_each = local.endpoints
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  service_name = each.value

  #filter {
  #  name = "tag:AWSNetworkFirewallManaged"
  #  values = [true]
  #}
}

resource "aws_route" "tgw_route" {
  count                  = var.number_azs
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.tgw_rt[count.index].id
  destination_cidr_block = var.tgw_aws_route[0]
  vpc_endpoint_id        = data.aws_vpc_endpoint.firewall-endpoints["service_name"].id
}
```

Comment: The vpc_endpoint data resource is only ever going to return a singular endpoint. You should be doing the for_each in your route impl.

Comment: @Rome_Leader I think you weren't done explaining. Some text is missing.

Comment: Can you just use the `endpoint_id`s returned by [`aws_networkfirewall_firewall`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/aaronfeng/aws/latest/docs/resources/networkfirewall_firewall#sync_states) in the `sync_states` list? Then you won't need to create the endpoint data sources at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this, but I think what you want to do is something like this:

```hcl
resource "aws_route" "tgw_route" {
  for_each = aws_networkfirewall_firewall.firewall_status.sync_states

  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.tgw_rt[???].id
  destination_cidr_block = var.tgw_aws_route[0]
  vpc_endpoint_id        = each.value.attachment.endpoint_id
}
```

I'm not clear on the structure of the `firewall_status` output, so that may need to change slightly. The main question is how to get the appropriate route table ID per subnet. Can you access the outputs of the `tgw_rt` module in some way other than by index? Unfortunately, I have no experience with setting up an AWS firewall, just with Terraform, so I don't know how to solve this part of the puzzle.

Comment: Hi @Nick K9 this issue has been resolved. I'd rather have the resource block in the VPC state file, therefore the only thing I would have to worry about is retrieving the endpoints. I used your suggestions from the other post, but I gave up using ONE data vpc_endpoint resource but rather two to find one at a time. Not exactly what I a want to do but it works.